# CSS - Exibir texto centralizado com outro texto alinhado à lateral

Tags: css

Possuo uma `div` de 70% de largura da página e com o texto centralizado.

Eu preciso colocar uma frase no canto direito mas na mesma linha que o texto original, sem atrapalhar a centralização do texto original.

```css
#mainContent {
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
}
#bottomContent {
    z-index:-1;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#999;
    font-size:10px;
    background: #e8e8e8; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e8e8e8 0%, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e8e8e8 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e8e8e8 0%,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e8e8e8', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.RodapeDireita {
    font-size:10px;
    z-index:1;
    float:right;    
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
      <!--Aqui vai o restante do site-->
      <div id="bottomContent">
        <span style="font-size:12px">
            Nome da empresa<br />
            Endere&ccedil;o da empresa<br />
            Telefone da empresa
        </span>
        <span class="RodapeDireita">
            &copy;Copyright da Empresa
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

No caso acima, como eu posso fazer para que o Copyright da empresa não "empurre" o Telefone da empresa para a esquerda?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você puder usar um `position:absolute;` pode utilizar para alinhar somente a `div` de "copyright" na lateral. Mas tome cuidado, pois em resoluções menores, ele pode ficar 'por cima' do texto centralizado.

É importante notar que você deve definir a sua `div` pai com um `position: relative;` para que o `absolute` esteja "relativamente" posicionado à div pai.

```
#bottomContent {
    z-index:-1;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#000;
    background: #e8e8e8;
    position:relative;
}
```

Depois basta aplicar o posicionamento na `div` que deseja alinhar na lateral, definindo a distância da lateral e a distancia de baixo.

```
.RodapeDireita {
    font-size:10px;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:5px;
    right:5px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Veja este exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/nugx9vso/3/

Obs.: mudei o seu html de `<span>` para `<ul>` pois fica melhor de estruturar a sua coluna centralizada, e também removi o gradiente para visualizar melhor.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Segui a sua dica do <ul> também. Obrigado novamente.

Comment: Não foi nada! Bom desenvolvimento, jovem.